# how to make flexbox work with listis <ul> <li>

Tags: list, flexbox, html-lists, center

I need to create sidebar where I will have 3 words, they need to be in the middle spread even in column and this needs to be done in the list

.

How to do it properly??

I try to use on it flexbox formula:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-content: space-around;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33371765/3597276

Comment: I need list not DIVs, but thank You :)

Comment: Same idea. Use list elements instead of divs.